# Can't resolve method className()

Tags: java, classname

I can't figure out why i have an error on this piece of code. Any suggestion?

Thanks

```
public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice = 2;

    choice.className().getName();

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You Cannot invoke className() on primitive type

Comment: So, how do i check that "choice" is actually an int ?

Comment: you can either use  Integer.parseInt(). Or if you want to use class name, use wrapper instead (Integer) and choice.getClass().getName()

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because primitives are not objects.

> If the fully-qualified name of a class is available, it is possible to get the corresponding Class using the static method Class.forName(). This cannot be used for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine primitive variable data type like that way.
code should be like below.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice = 2;
    String type = ((Object)choice).getClass().getName();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it is of primitive type, but you can use Integer instead
and to check if it belongs to specific object you can use

```
Object temp = 1;
if(temp  instanceof Integer){
 System.out.println("Integer Object");
}
```